# PHP JSON and Twitter

Tags: php, json, api, twitter

```
<?
$Tweet = file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=EdVizenor&count=1");

//$Tweet = explode(",",$Tweet);
/// If I explode and echo the $Tweet(3); i get .... "text":"mY LATEST TWEET"

var_dump(json_decode($Tweet,true));
?>
```

What I want to do is parse out the array via key. Something like:

```
echo $Tweet(text);  /// but this does not work.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to know what the error is. The problem is that `$Tweet(text)` would be calling a function contained in `$Tweet`, since that variable is not a function, but an actual array, you actually just have to

```
<?php
// your code
$tweets = json_decode($Tweet,true);
echo $tweets[0]['text'];
```

Next time, be sure to include the error being thrown, it is very helpful for you to read and understand those!

Comment: What do you mean by "active"?

Comment: So I can click on them. right now it's just text. But it would be great if it would see them as links and people can click the links I post on twitter.

Comment: Thanks. I think this link might be what I was asking about... tho I have not tested it. http://tech.cibul.net/turn-urls-into-links-in-text-with-jquery/